# Fabric Canvas - Image resolution is very poor

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs, resolution

I'm implementing `Fabricjs` in my application for an editing tool. I need to set a high resolution image into the canvas. If I use `setBackgroundImage` method, it is only working for small sized (Size very less than canvas) images. So I need to reduce the size of the image (but need to keep the ratio) to have something good looking.

My first idea is down sampling which works fine for some pictures but not for all. Here is the code :

**Method 1)**

```
var steps = 2;
var imgAspect = img.width / img.height;
var oc = document.createElement('canvas');
octx = oc.getContext('2d');

for(var i = 0; i < steps; i++){
    if(i == 0){
        oc.width = img.width * 0.5;
        oc.height = img.height * 0.5;
        octx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, oc.width, oc.height);
    }
    else{
        octx.drawImage(oc, 0, 0, oc.width * 0.5, oc.height * 0.5);
    }
}

_w = canvas.width;
_h = canvas.height;

ctx.drawImage(oc, 0, 0, oc.width * 0.5, oc.height * 0.5, 0, 0, _w, _h);

var data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
var c = document.createElement('canvas');
c.setAttribute('id', '_temp_canvas');
c.width = canvas.width;
c.height = canvas.height;
c.getContext('2d').putImageData(data, 0, 0);

var img = fabric.Image.fromURL(c.toDataURL(), function(img) {
    img.left = 00;
    img.top = 00;
    img.isFixed = true;
    img.selectable = false;
    canvas.add(img);
    c = null;
    $('#_temp_canvas').remove();

    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

My second idea, I'm following from [here](https://gist.github.com/makevoid/1659616) which looks very simple

```
var canvasCopy = document.createElement("canvas")
var copyContext = canvasCopy.getContext("2d")
var ratio = 1;

if(img.width > canvas.width){
    ratio = canvas.width / img.width;
}
else if(img.height > canvas.height){
    ratio = canvas.height / img.height;
}

canvasCopy.width = img.width;
canvasCopy.height = img.height;
copyContext.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

canvas.width = img.width * ratio;
canvas.height = img.height * ratio;

ctx.drawImage(canvasCopy, 0, 0, canvasCopy.width, canvasCopy.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

The issue is none of them producing good resolution. Method 1 works well for some pictures but it is failed for few pictures. If I try the method 2 it is working for the failed pictures from method 1. Can somebody help what is missing regarding the resolution ?

See the [fiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/ewgbcadL/6/) and [fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/ewgbcadL/10/) with 2 different images. You can see the difference by calling the `method1` and `method2` in the `_img.onload` function to see the difference.

Comment: You should not be using the browser to edit high resolution images, there are specialize tools for that such as Photoshop and Gimp ...

Comment: But if you are set on creating something with a canvas you should consider breaking the high resolution images server side and then on the browser you will use image tiles, similar to what online maps use, that way you can pan and zoom then your edits will go back server side to be applied to the original image

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. So server side implementation is the best optio. Isn't it?

Comment: If you want to deal with  high resolution images yes that is your best bet.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is your case, but for me worked `imageSmoothingEnabled=false` like

```
var canvasCopy = document.createElement("canvas")
var copyContext = canvasCopy.getContext("2d")
copyContext.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
```

reference http://fabricjs.com/lanczos-webgl